# С++ работа с памятью, шаблоны

Tags: c++, память, шаблоны-с++, sizeof

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename type>
int size(type a) {
    return sizeof(a);
}

int main() {
    int a[10] = {5};
    cout << size(a) << " " << sizeof(a) << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Здравствуйте! Пожалуйста можете объяснить почему `size(a)` возвращает `8`, а `sizeof(a)` - `40`? И как внутри шаблона функции получить информацию об использованной массивом памяти? Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном случае `a` в шаблоне не будет массивом, так как массивы нельзя передавать по значению, а аргументы-массивы неявно переделываются в аргументы-указатели. В этом можно легко убедиться, добавив в метод проверку:

```
static_assert(::std::is_same_v<int *, type>);
```

Для корректного определения размера исходного объекта придется передавать его по ссылке:

```
template <typename type>
::std::size_t size(type const & a) {
    return sizeof(a);
}
```

Comment: то есть мы передаем не массив а ссылку на массив, так? А что делает ключевое слово `const` в этом конкретном примере? И чем отличается `size_t` от `int`: это сделано только для удобства или как?

Comment: @ՀայկԱվետիսյան Да, передаем ссылку на массив неизменяемых элементов. `std::size_t` это специальный тип, в который гарантировано помещается размер объектов (`int` может быть недостаточно). `sizeof` возвращает именно `std::size_t`, а не просто `size_t` или `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Компилятор вполне может вычеслять `type`(по аргументу функции) как тип, содержащий  столько то обьектов, так как может вызываться `std::size`. И  для следующей программы:

```
int a[15] = { 5 };  
cout << size(a); //15
```

получим результат     15

В общем случаи всегда лучше  аргументы шаблонной функции передавать по ссыльке и не использовать имена из стандартной библиотеки, и не использовать все имена из `std` (`using namespace std` )

Comment: Почему же не надо писать `using namespace std`? Это загружает память или как?

Comment: Просто  в такм случаи все имена из пространства std становятся  доступными и более приоритетным. Если это в маленькой программе не мешает, то  нет проблем. Но, например для вашего примера  это уже приведет к тому, что не ваша функция вызовится, а вызовится std::size, который   возвращает количество элементов контейнера(в данном случаи массива)